# Python one thread writing to end of file and another thread reading from beginning of file

Tags: python, multithreading, file-io

I have one thread writing a line to the end of a file every so often and I was hoping to have another thread read from the beginning of the file and then delete what it had read. I need it to be in a file so that when the program ends it can pick up where it left off. The problem is that I'm not sure how to delete the first line and then refresh the file.

Comment: Please add some code that you have tried

Answer (score 1):

Files don't work that way. You can read a file or write it, but you cannot easily delete the first line from a file. You'd have to go to the start of the file and overwrite it with the data from the second and further lines and then truncate it at the end.

A better alternative would be to keep a list of lines in a module.
In that module, define two functions;

- One to add lines to the end of the list (using the `append` method).
- The second to remove lines from the beginning of the list and return them (using the `pop` method with 0 as the argument).

You should add a third function to write the list to a file (using the file's `writelines` method). If desired, you can call this function in both of the other functions so that the list is written to file whenever it has changed.
Last but not least you should have a function to load a list of lines from a file.

Since you want to use this from a multi-threaded program this module should use a `threading.Lock` to make sure that only one thread at a time can modify the list.